# Changing Named Range with manual calculation

Tags: excel, named-ranges, vba

I have a *named range* that changes during a macro operation.

For reasons of efficiency, I set the `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` but the named range doesn´t change anymore.

Do you know of a way to upgrade the dynamic range while staying in the manual calculation mode?

Comment: do not use a named range use a variable with reference to range

Comment: or try `Range("myNamedRange").Calculate`

Comment: 'I have a named range that changes during a macro operation.' << which code does it for you, show that part of your solution.

Comment: Hi, I tried with `Range("myNamedRange").Calculate ` but I get a erratic behavior. What it worked was to Calculate the entire sheet that contains the elements of my range, but in terms of efficiency is far from what I expect. My is code is 
`For Each c In [MyRange1] <br/>
     '... code
     For Each d In [MyRange2]
         '... more code`
    next
next`
     



`